# Can I rewrite a URL, adding query params and preserve the form data?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, apache2, mod-jk

I have a rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)\.t(.*)\.(\w+)?\.sprawk\.com:(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /api/translateHtmlPublic?tl=%1&su=%2&p=$1&q=%4 [B,PT,L]
```

which works great for GET requests.

However, for POST requests, the q parameter is null (which I expected) but inside my Java servlet, both the `HttpServletRequest.getReader()` and `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()` give no data.

Using Firefox Live headers, I see that I am sending:

```
POST /uid/contactSend.cfm HTTP/1.1
Host: fr.t51940.local.sprawk.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://fr.t51940.local.sprawk.com/uid/contact.cfm?country=137
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 146
userName=Nic&queryCountry=Libya&queryCode=137&userEmail=n.cottrell%40idea.int&Comment=Just+testing&captcha=Quotas&Submit=--+Envoyer+Commentaire+--
```

I know that the servlet is receiving it as a `POST` since the `doPost` method is triggered. I understand that Apache 2.x should automatically preserve POST data during a simple rewrite, but maybe the addition of parameters is wiping the content data?

Update: I just realised (by dumping out all parameters) that the userName, queryCountry, queryCode parameters are getting correct values via the `request.getParameter(String)` method. The problem is that I need to be able to separate the original form parameter names from the ones I introduction in the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

1. The parameters of a POST are in the body, not the header. You can rewrite the URL as much as you like without affecting them.
2. The body of a POST request whose content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` consists only of parameters that are retrieved via `request.getParameter().` Reading the body via `request.getInputStream()` and `request.getReader()` will deliver nothing. (Servlet Specification 3, #3.1.1)
3. According to Servlet Specifcation #3, the parameters you add to the URL should be retrievable via `getParameter()`.
4. There is no way to distinguish POST parameters in the body from URL parameters in the header. There is probably therefore something wrong with your solution, or your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the details. My backup plan is to introduce a long prefix to my variables, so that the chance of conflicting with an existing name is very low. I was hoping that there was a way of telling the servlet to /not/ automatically process the body and make the data available by `getParameter`